# Main section heading in footer

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr

I would like to have a footer on every page containing the *main* section (always the name of the current `\section`, not `\subsection`) and the current page, e.g.

```
My section heading | 42
```

Bonus level: Pages with a `\section` should only contain the page, not the heading or |

This is what I've got so far. Not really what I want but at least a starting point.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1{\bfseries~|~}}}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1{\bfseries~|~}}}
\renewcommand{\subsubsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1{\bfseries~|~}}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyfoot[R]{\sffamily{\small\rightmark}{\bfseries\thepage}}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\Blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possibility using the [`titleps`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titleps) package:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{titleps}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newpagestyle{mystyle}{\setfoot{}{}{\sectiontitle~$\mid$~\thepage}}
\newpagestyle{mypage}{\setfoot{}{}{\thepage}}
\pagestyle{mystyle}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{\@startsection}{\thispagestyle{mypage}\@startsection}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

And here's the same, but with `fancyhdr`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[R]{\rightmark~$\mid$~\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{mypage}{
  \fancyhf{}
  \fancyfoot[R]{\thepage}
  \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\section}{\@startsection}{\thispagestyle{mypage}\@startsection}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section One}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Test Section Two}
\lipsum[1-20]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `fancyhdr` approach doesn't print a section heading for me, only `| 42` but I am absolutely happy with your `titleps` solution. Thank you so much!